# Chemical Structures as Graph Labels in R

Tags: molecular-structure

I asked the following question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236135/chemical-structures-as-graph-labels-in-r but I ask it here for a different perspective.

I want to make a plot that labels a point with the chemical structure represented by the value at that point.

In the example below I have a plot of melting points which are labelled by the smiles strings of the molecules.

```
chem_data <- c(40.5, -6.3, -44)

names(chem_data) <- c("c1ccc(cc1)O", "Nc1ccccc1", "Fc1ccccc1" )

plot(chem_data, main="Example Plot\n Labelled with Smiles String", ylim=c(-50,50), xlim=c(0,4),
     ylab="mp /°C")

text(chem_data, labels=names(chem_data), cex= 0.7, pos=1)
```

How do I label the points with the chemical structures rather than the smiles strings?

Can R generate the image of the chemical structure from the smiles string?

Comment: It won't get your data points "labeled" by SMILES-based structure pictures yet by it seems CheminerR either alone, or working together with openabel is able to convert similes into pictures as by this post: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ChemmineR/inst/doc/ChemmineR.html.  An other post suggests  rcdk and rpubchem (http://www.cureffi.org/2013/09/23/a-quick-intro-to-chemical-informatics-in-r/). (I have no experience at all with R so far.)

Comment: thanks so far ... I was thinking of rcdk but I was hoping that others would point me in the right direction.